# REST event process action define using xml

Tags: xml, events, methods, action

Hi I'm building a REST service using LAMP.

Too make it clear for everyone (not just dev), I thinking what if we write all the event action in a xml file.

It will define the event and the class method relation or even the business process.

E.g

```xml
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" >
    <event id="procurement.order.get.id">
        <action>
        <call method="procurement.getOrderById" />
        <parameters type="input">
            <resource value="http_request.get.id" />
        </parameters>
        <parameters type="output">
            <resource key="event_resource.procurement.order_id" value="procurement.getId" />
            <resource key="event_resource.procurement.order_date" value="procurement.getOrderDate" />
        </parameters>
        </action>
        <action>
           ...
        </action>
    </event>
</xml>
```

The drawback here might be speed, but I'll parse this xml on first call create a good php array and cache it. Since it will not change often, I think there won't be any other disadvantage. and second we can validate it with a xml schema.

so Is it worth it ?

Comment: This sounds similar to WADL, you may want to see if you can accomplish what you're doing using that, since it's already an open standard with libraries in several langauages. See http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/

Comment: WADL seems to complex, I just to want to note what this event do, and what business logic it load ... but I also concern that it not usable in other programming language ...